# @keyframes animation on SVG not working

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG with two nested `g` elements with classes, `.logo-path-1` and `.logo-path-2`. I have built two `@keyframes` blink animations so that the two nested elements alternate blinking, however only one is currently working.

I have tried compressing the SVG and have looked at the `g` elements several times. I have also tried to use the `animation-delay: .25s;` attribute to reduce number of `@keyframes` but I can not get the second `g` to animate properly.

SVG too large to embed snippet, here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/karsonkalt/pen/EmmVQG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the seconds unit ("s") on line 39:

```
-webkit-animation: blink-2 .25 infinite;
```

It should be:

```
-webkit-animation: blink-2 .25s infinite;
```

Update [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Chris-Happy/pen/mmmPOz?editors=0100).